# how to create jbehave report with jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jbehave

i have some set of jbehave tests and regular jenkins job with xunit plugin that create report from xml files. So far so good. Now, unfortunately i need to add some actions and it is easier to add them in pipeline. But i don't get how to generate jbehave report in pipeline. Been trying to use 'pipeline-syntax' help but this page only generate `xunit([<object of type org.jbehave.jenkins.JBehavePluginType>])`